# search a text file for some text if exists change text inside ""

Tags: c#-4.0

ok i was wondring what is the best way to attempt to read a whole text file for some text if it finds the text it changes the text inside the "" i know this can be done but i never really looked into this or had to do this before and im not sure how to approach it. this is the stuff im looking for.

this is the sort of code i want to change

```
add_weapon( "b23r" );
```

and it finds add_weapon ("replace whats in here....");

because i have a program when i hit the check box i want to make it so if i copy over a pistol i can make it the start weapon but to do that i need to replace the b23r  with the new weapon name when i push the check box and hit copy weapons i want it to replace that name with the weapon copying over.

so for example

```
if (zombie_colt == true ) 
{
 add_weapon( "zombie_colt" );  
}
```

something along those lines because i want it to only work for pistols i just dont know the best way to read tho a text file look for that find the quotes and change whats inside those

i looked into regex but it really confuses me and was asking here to see if anyone knows of a better way of accomplishing this

thanks in advance elfenliedtopfan5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite vague but if I understand what you're looking for - you want to replace all instances of some text (in a text file) with a different value.
Because you were talking about regex, here is a short example to get you started for doing this using regex:

```
const string FILENAME = <path to your file>;

string data = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
Regex r = new Regex(@"add_weapon\( ""[0-9A-Za-z_]+"" \);");
string s = r.Replace(data, "add_weapon( \"REPLACE_HERE\" );");
File.WriteAllText(FILENAME, s);
```

Replace the `REPLACE_HERE` in line 4 with whatever you need.
In addition - I recommend reading more about **[Regex.Replace](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace)**

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your reply i will give this a go and read more into it thank you for your response and so quickly to :)